# Constructing composite attribute in Rails with an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create a table in Ruby on rails with association `Location` which consists of multiple variables, here's the Location attribute:

```
Location: (city, country, district, street, flat number, floor, landmark)
```

How to represent this in ruby on rails syntax? I'm a bit new to it and I can't quite know how to do this.

Comment: You mean you wanted to create `Locations` table with `city, country, district, street, flat number, floor, landmark` fields?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [create new Table in ruby on rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388756/create-new-table-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: No Location is a table attribute, my main table is:
User :
Id , Firstname, Lastname, email, Location (city, country, district, street, flat number, floor, landmark)

Answer (score 2):

Generate `Location` model:

```
rails g model Location city:string country:string district:string street:string flat_number:string floor:integer landmark:string
```

then run `rake db:migrate`

**Note:** In above command `Location` is model name and it's table generated with Plural of model name so your table name will be `locations`. after that there are `field_name:data_type`

---

as per your comment you wanted to add fields in `users` table(existing) then in this case to add fields in existing table:

```
rails generate migration AddLocationToUser city:string country:string district:string street:string flat_number:string floor:integer landmark:string
```

then run `rake db:migrate`
this will add fields to your users table.

for more info http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html

There is very nice official rails guideline http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org

Comment: "nice" answer for someone, who has no idea of what model is and what difference there is between variable and attribute.. Just provide OP with the link to rails guides - this will be the only potentially useful thing for him.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko : Thank you :) I have added `Ruby on Rails Guides` link for reference

Comment: No Location is a table attribute, my main table is: User :- Id , Firstname, Lastname, email, Location (city, country, district, street, flat number, floor, landmark), I don't know how to represent Location in the create model command

Comment: @Loaa : so you mean you wanted to add these fields in `users` table? I have update my answer for this case also. If this is not what you want then please let me know in details exactly what you want?

Comment: You can also maintain separate table for locations and give relation to user table. So you can easily access user's location from this relation through user object.